# Create table from calculation of three other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables. They are

T1:

```
Date          product       price
19501010       xxx          p0
19501011       xxx          p1
...
```

Where Date are stored as int.

T2:

```
 Date         Product      price_suddenly_change
 19200120        yaz            -0.1
 ...
```

T3:

```
 Date    Product     post   pre   
19240912   xxy       100    20
```

Where post and pre stand for the numbers of product increase from pre to post on that day.(If this happen, the price in Table T1 should be reflected, say in this example, after changing from 20 to 100, the price in T1 should be price=price*0.2. )

I want to create one table from T1, T2 and T3, which looks like:

```
Date      product   price_change_percentage 
19501010   xxx        12%
19501011   xxx        3%
...
```

Where

> price_change_percentage=(p1-p0+price_suddenly_change)/p0

, p1 and p0 are in T1, price_suddenly_change are in T2, and I also have to consider T3 for product number change.

If my T1 is huge (>40M rows), how can I solve the problem please?

Update: for T3's handling. if in T3, the product number change in some date (say 1 to 10), then one can see a sharp price change in T1 (say p1 change to $ 100 to $10). However, in this case, I don't want to count it as a "change" in my percentage calculation. If any other conditions are unchanged (no sudden price change), I want to return price_change_percentage=0.

Comment: your question is a little unclear, how do you `"consider T3 for product number change"` also change the sample data to real data instead of `p0` and `p1` to be more understandable

Comment: Based on what condition? Does exists any relationship between tables?

Comment: Thank you for all your reply. For Ferheg's question, if in T3, the product number change in some date (say 1 to 10), then one can see a sharp price change in T1 (say $ 100 to $10). However, in this case, I don't want to count it as a "change" in my percentage calculation. If any other conditions are unchanged (no sudden price change and p1-p0=0), I want to return price_change_percentage=0.

Comment: Sorry it should like this:  if in T3, the product number change in some date (say 1 to 10), then one can see a sharp price change in T1 (say p1 change to $ 100 to $10). However, in this case, I don't want to count it as a "change" in my percentage calculation. If any other conditions are unchanged (no sudden price change), I want to return price_change_percentage=0.